# What is the difference between these two relative paths?

Tags: html, url, path, relative-path

When I browse the source of websites, sometimes I see links like this:

```
<a href="css/screen.css"></a>
```

...and sometimes I see links like this:

```
<a href="/css/screen.css"></a>
```

What is the difference between these two relative paths, if any, and why should I use one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is relative to the directory of the current resource. The second is relative to the root web directory.

Comment: That is what I suspected. Thanks!